# How to serialize class with string with already JSON

Tags: json, string, vb.net, json.net

I'm completely new to JSON.NET-serialization and desperately need some extra help.

I have a simple class like this, which needs to be serialized to a JSON string:

```
Public Class TestObject
    Public n1 As Integer
    Public n2 As Integer
    Public str1 As String
    Public str2 As String
End Class
```

And I try to serialize it to JSON like this:

```
Dim tst As TestObject = New TestObject
With tst
    .n1 = 12
    .n2 = 15
    .str1 = "The name"
    .str2 = "{""prop1"": ""val1""}"
End With
Dim obj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tst)
```

The result is:

> {"n1":12,"n2":15,"str1":"The name","str2":"{\"prop1\": \"val1\"}"}

But what I need to have is:

> {"n1":12,"n2":15,"str1":"The name","str2":{"prop1": "val1"}}

The result will be send to my web-client.
I tried several attributes but none have the required effect.

If this is not possible then I go for the second best solution which is:

> {"n1":12,"n2":15,"str1":"The name","str2":"{""prop1"": ""val1""}"}

Any suggestion how to realise this?

Regards,

Arno.

Comment: Redeclare the property to be `JObject`, then deserialize your string into that before serialization through `JObject.Parse`.

Comment: @Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen, can you give an example? JOBJECT and JOBJECT.Parse are not avaialble in my code.

Comment: They should be since you're using Json.Net.

Comment: Yep, y're right. I added "Imports Newtonsoft.Json.Linq" also and now both are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve that, you could assign to `str2` some unique character string, serialize it and then in serialized JSON you could replace it.

I put that logic in class method, like this:

```
Public Class TestObject
    Public n1 As Integer
    Public n2 As Integer
    Public str1 As String
    Public str2 As String

    Public Function SerializeMe() As String
        Dim internalJson = str2
        'assign to str2 some unique string, to replace it after serialization
        str2 = "SomeUniqueCharacterSequence"
        SerializeMe = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Me).Replace(str2, internalJson)
        'assign back the value of str2, so we won't change state of an object
        str2 = internalJson
    End Function
End Class
```

Then, using it in code like below will give you desired result:

```
Dim tst As TestObject = New TestObject
With tst
    .n1 = 12
    .n2 = 15
    .str1 = "The name"
    .str2 = "{""prop1"": ""val1""}"
End With
Dim obj = tst.SerializeMe()
```

Comment: This requires changes to the web api project as well, which may or may not be the right solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the overload method to remove the formatting.

```
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(source,Formatting.None);
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I tried your suggestion but the result is the same.

Comment: This won't help, the string is **correctly** serialized for json, the problem here is that the string shouldn't be serialized at all, OP wants the string inserted verbatim and I don't think json.net will do that. I think the correct course of action is to add objects that will be serialized in order to produce the expected outcome instead.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to both Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen & Michal Turczyn, I now have two solutions, which work fine.

I only have to choose….
For my code I just implemented the following, because it was the easiest way:

```
    Public Class TestObject
        Public n1 As Integer
        Public n2 As Integer
        Public str1 As String
        Public str2 As JObject
    End Class

    Dim tst As TestObject = New TestObject
    With tst
        .n1 = 12
        .n2 = 15
        .str1 = "The name"
        .str2 = JObject.Parse("{""prop1"": ""val1""}")
   End With


    Dim obj = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tst)
```

Thanks a lot.